# Using controller in subdirectory in Codeigniter

Tags: routes, codeigniter-3

I'd like to create an admin panel for my app.

I created a view file in

```
 views/admin/dashboard.php
```

I also created a controller in

```
controllers/Admin/Admin.php
```

i'd like to access the page via mysite.com/admin/

When I put the controller file into the root of the controllers folder, it works, but when I put the file in a subdirectory I get 404 error. i'm guessing I don't use the proper routing. I checked Codeigniter's docs on routing but couldn't figure out what would work for me.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

please visit http://yoursite.com/admin/admin/ to you organize controller in subfolder

Visit https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/controllers.html#id10

Comment: Thanks for the reply, and it works, but I'd like to access the page by going to mysite.com/admin/

Comment: So use route To sub directory

Answer (score 0):

This routing worked for me:

```
$route['admin'] = "admin/admin";
```

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter cannot find the controller inside folders.
Don't create a folder.[(For more information. Click here!)](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/controllers.html)

Comment: From codeigniter documentation: "If you are building a large application you might want to hierarchically organize or structure your controllers into sub-directories. CodeIgniter permits you to do this."